# Where to put a tracking implant?

Tags: internal-consistency, medicine

A small device, the size of a grain of rice, is implanted in a number of individuals to track their movement. These individuals are usually compliant but being tracked is also not exactly in their interest. For this reason the organization decided to place the implant in a body part that makes extraction difficult/dangerous at least for an amateur. On the other hand they do not want for the set up procedure to be too much of a hassle.

What is a good place in the human body for such a device? Insertion should be possible without anesthetic (local is allowed) and treated individuals should require no hospitalization. Location must not pose a threat over long term and limbs are not allowed.

EDIT: My question is hardly a duplicate of the provided question. That question revolves more around security features and NONE of the answers provided deal with the location (what I asked) of such a device in any meaningful way.

Comment: considering your edit you might want to look at this question then? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/81603/personal-identification-chip-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @dot_Sp0T I already saw that question, it talks about set up at birth that is hard to remove. It doesn't really fit my request and all answers point at the brain which clearly doesn't fit the parameters I gave.

Comment: then 1) add why your question is different than both of these questions (best make 1 paragraph per other question, even link to them, and explain in 1-3 sentences where the difference is). From my understanding at least the second question is pretty much the same thing - it also has, contra to what you claim, answers that do not point to the brain. Help us help you.

Answer (score 4):

Since limbs aren't allowed, I'd suggest the butt cheek.  There's lots of room to hide the chip, which I think can be as small as a grain of rice anyway, and there are existing shots that need to be in that location anyway.

Simply have a pretext of inoculation against legitimate X infection and install it with a syringe.  It can even include the legit inoculation, so you wouldn't even (technically) be lying to them.  Now you have their buy-in to get this shot, it doesn't need any anesthetic, the medics shouldn't need any extra training, and the pain is from a known reason.

Heck, this is covered by existing conspiracy theories, so if they talk to anyone about their fears, they just sound crazy.  ;-)

Comment: "lots of room" ... just what are you implying, buster?  ;D

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about the size of my own, when posting...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems many are assuming the process is supposed to be a secret? I like your answer anyway

Comment: It's still a secret, but an "open" one.  Nothing smells more of a secret than hush-hush operations.  Something done "in the wide open clear" as a standard procedure doesn't raise anyone's guard.  Only the most paranoid will even think twice about it, and they'll sound crazy even before the shot, so will be less likely to be believed from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Ingested, potentially?
How high tech is your tracker? Could it resist stomach acid? Stick to an intestine? Slipping it into someone's food could well be the easiest way to get it into someone without them noticing.
The only problem here could be the obvious: *passing* it. However, if the tech is far enough advanced, this tracker of yours could attach itself inside the person - and could be rid of easily if the person who placed it there no longer wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the human equivalent of a dog microchip would work well? [See this reference](https://www.petfinder.com/dogs/lost-and-found-dogs/how-microchips-implanted/). They are similar in size to the trackers you describe, they can be implanted easily under a local anaesthetic and no hospitalization is required. Although human anatomy is obviously different from that of a dog or a horse the basic principle remains the same. The tracker can be injected under the skin anywhere although the back of the neck near the shoulder blades seems to be a good place.

If this is too easily removed by an amateur with a scalpel (!), then the same process could be used to inject into the fatty layers around the midriff. This would be very much harder to remove once it’s in and the incision has healed.

Answer (score 1):

**In the neck near an artery**

A gun can be easily manufactured to safely implant such a device in the hands of a TRAINED individual. This is because it can be inserted relatively closely to the surface of the skin yet be in a place where unskilled extraction can be fatal.

Digging around in the neck anywhere near major blood vessels is fatal.

Anesthesia is unnecessary as this could be done as quickly as a vaccine injection and roughly at the same pain level.

Places that are bad are:

- on the spine: placing on the spine can be easily extracted because the bone protects the spinal chord. Granted it would suck but it is doable by a novice.
- in the spine: impractical because this would likely cause extreme discomfort or be fata.
- behind the spine: impractical because it would take exhaustive surgical effort to get it there. There is danger in hitting critical nerves that come off the spinal chord.
- near organs: impractical because it requires exhaustive surgical effort in traversing muscles, nerves, and blood vessels. Its simple too deep in the body.
- butt cheeks: Is just a muscle, you could dig that out albeit to large degrees of pain and potential short to longterm mobility handicaps.

Answer (score 0):

Under an existing scar or injury.  Any discomfort or itching will be attributed to the pre-existing feature and not raise suspicion.

If it’s under the skin, noplace is more “dangerous” than another.

Answer (score 0):

How about behind the ear under the skin? Potentially where the ear connects with the head

This would be a very hidden spot, and the person being tracked would probably never notice a scar or bump. It would cause no harm to the one being tracked, and could be secretly inserted when someone is getting their ear pierced.

Comment: Welcome to World building Spybug96

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be under the skin, near/on top of the spine, in the center of the person's back.

Your back itches sometimes for no reason, and you rarely ever get a good look at the area without contorting in front of a mirror. Plus, a person wouldn't be able to mess with it without help.

Having a tattoo on my back, there are times where I completely forget that it's even there.